# Como se chama o callback no javascript quando este está nomeado (diretamente na declaração)?

Tags: javascript, funções

Como se chama o callback no javascript quando este está nomeado (diretamente na declaração)?

Exemplo:

Declaração comum de uma função:

```
function fn()
{
    console.log(fn); // Imprime fn()
    return 'do';
}

fn(); // 'do
```

Declaração (não sei se é assim que se chama) ao mesmo tempo que passamos por callback:

```
call(function fn()
{
    console.log(fn); // Imprime: fn()
});

fn(); // Erro: função não foi definida
```

Outro exemplo:

```
$('element').on('action', function fn()
{
    if ($(this).next().size()) {
        fn.call(this);
    }
});

console.log(fn)// Erro: Função não definida
```

- Qual é a diferença dessa foram de nomeação das funções?
- Um é uma declaração e o outro é uma expressão?
- Isso pode ser chamado de função anônima (já que ela tem um nome, mesmo que seja apenas para aquele escopo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22173438/3096922) no SOEN, são nomeados da seguinte forma:

## function declaration ou declaração de função

Nesse caso é a declaração comum da função.

Exemplo:

```
function fn()
{
}
```

## named function expression Expressão de função nomeada

Nesse caso, é uma expressão passada como callback de outra chamada de função, a que se é dado um nome, podendo ser referenciada dentro do escopo que é chamada.

Exemplo:

```
$('.item').eq(0).fadeIn(500, function fade()
{
     fade.id = typeof(fade.id) == 'undefined' ? 1 : ++fade.id;

     if ($('.item').eq(fade.id).size()) {
        $('.item').eq(fade.id).fadeIn(500, fade);
     }
});
```

Nesse caso, é uma expressão nomeada, passada por callback de `fadeIn`. Também foi possível atribuir à expressão `fade` o atributo `id`.

Se tentássemos acessar seu atributo fora daquele escopo, haveria um erro, pois se trata de uma expressão de função nomeada, e não uma função declarada com aquele nome.